# how to add 'more info' link inside image and display the content within the image size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add **more info** link inside an image and when I click on it i want the description of the image to be displayed within the image area.
[image: normal image]

When user hover mouse on in it should show **more info** option. [image: more info link]

When user selects more info, description should appear within the image [image: description of the image]

and back to normal when clicks outside the image.

```
<div class="content">
    <img id="adj" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="Chrysanthemum" width="300" height="200">
    <a href="#">more info</a>
</div>`
```

i want to force the more info inside the image's bottom right corner.

Comment: Not a problem even if the **more info** is visible all the time.

Comment: @Wavemaster I tried `<div> <a> <img> </a> </div>` and vice versa but the link appears outside the image box. trying postion:absolute and relative now.

Comment: Please add the whole code of the image with the link and the text to your question. Preferably in a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some CSS to do the trick:

(But it's not with click, instead it's with hover)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
div:hover a {
  display: block;
}
img {
  position: relative;
}
a {
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: cursive;
}
a:hover + span,
span:hover {
  display: block;
}
span {
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img id="adj" src="http://placekitten.com/133/120" alt="Chrysanthemum">
  <a href="#">more info</a>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img id="adj" src="http://placekitten.com/200/120" alt="Chrysanthemum">
  <a href="#">more info</a>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img id="adj" src="http://placekitten.com/133/120" alt="Chrysanthemum">
  <a href="#">more info</a>
  <span>litr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et </span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img id="adj" src="http://placekitten.com/333/120" alt="Chrysanthemum">
  <a href="#">more info</a>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img id="adj" src="http://placekitten.com/133/120" alt="Chrysanthemum">
  <a href="#">more info</a>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor amet.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've 9 images in 3x3 grid! when i give position:relative other images are overlapping on them.

Comment: I've edited my post with `float:left;`. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a wrapper `<div>` for the image and than put the text and the button within that div.

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afik162534/d1qpoo47/1/) I just made, maybe it'll help